# filter records by selecting specific option from a drop-down list with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my HTML page I have a drop-down list with several options, which are some company names. I would like to get related records when I select certain company. I have no problem with this. But I want to add a "All" option at the top of the list and when I select "All" all the records will show up. Since I post the selected company name to back-end and do a normal sql query to find the records of which the company name is equal to the one I post, so I definitely cannot just post "All" to back-end. Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a neat way to achieve this.

Comment: All => *  setting this server side should not be so difficult...

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan I will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest (and neatest) is probably to put an if(){ statement server side.
So,

```
if($input == 'all'){
     $sql = <select all code>;
}else{
     $sql = <select any one code>;
}
```

and then run the `$sql` query.

Comment: Hi @chrisbradbury thank you for your answer. I actually thought about using an if-else to run the query. But in my code I have several drop-down list ,i.e. several filter conditions. So if I if-else, then there will be too many nested if-else statement.

Comment: you could use `WHERE x LIKE '%'` <-- this will return all the results, but probably requires an if.
or you can use `WHERE 1` which will return all the results

Comment: Hi @chrisbradbury at last I solve the problem by using if-else. What I do is kind of different from yours: first I write a sql which will retrieve all the records and for each condition input if $input != 'all', I will append a condition string like "AND company_name=$input..." so that if if I select all, nothing will be appended to the original sql and it will return all the records. Thank you for your help!